# Can someone tell me how to Configure Visual C++ 2015 with CPLEX?

Tags: visual-c++, cplex

I tried tutorial steps for Visual 2010, the linking didn't work or the console doesn't respond to build or run. I tried for other options to configure, which also didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may vote for a request for enhancement at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=85231
regards
Alex Fleischer

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit complicated...

First, I think you should start reading the following [tutorial](http://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-configure-ms-visual-studio-to-use-ibm-cplex-concert/). I find it quite straightforward as adapted to any CPLEX version. You must only *notice that* using a CPLEX version 12.X translates into the usage of its library: `cplex12X.lib`, the tutorial referring to CPLEX v12.61.

Then, you must install Visual Studio 2012, or even 2010, as they will install another Platform Toolset, v110 for VS2012 or v100 for VS2010. This is required since CPLEX comes with libraries for the 2010, 2012 and 2013 only, there is none so far for VS2015.

The configuration might work even if you have already VS2015 installed on your computer but I strongly advise you to begin installing the older version first, then the VS2015 to ensure the latter will recognize the older Platform Toolset and give you the option under: `View\Property Pages\Configuration Properties\General\Platform Toolset` of choosing the v110 for your project.

**Be aware that using only VS2015** will prompt you a bunch of *LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_msc_ver'* errors letting you know that you're using version 1800 whereas you're linking libraries compiled on 1600 or 1700 versions.

One is glad to be of service

Answer (score 0):

As of CPLEX 12.6.3, VS2015 is not supported (see the detailed system requirements [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100)).  It is possible to use VS2015 with a VS2013 project (e.g., see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)), but this is probably not what you are looking for.